# I cannot resolve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named error in Python

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror, windows-11

Files are located at C:\Projects\Pizza

In this directory, I have created an empty **init**.py, pizza.py, and make_pizza.py

file pizza.py contains the following:

```
def make_pizza(size, *toppings):
    """Summarize the pizza we are abou to make."""
    print("\nMaking a " + str(size) +
    "-inch pizza with the following toppings:")
    for topping in toppings:
        print("- " + topping)
```

file making_pizza.py contains the following:

```
import pizza

pizza.make_pizza(16, 'olives')
pizza.make_pizza(12, 'mushrooms', 'green peppers', 'extra cheese')
```

I have tried running this from Sublime and Geany

I am stuck...can someone give me some more ideas to check?

I double-checked environmental variables, created an **init**.py file, Reinstalled Python.

**My apologies for not including the Traceback earlier:**

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Projects\Pizza\making_pizzas.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pizza

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pizza'

[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]

[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Projects\Pizza\making_pizzas.py"]

[dir: C:\Projects\Pizza]

[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Python36\Python;C:\Users\kelly\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\Scripts;c:\users\kelly\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local\pip\cache\wheels\65\4f\66\bbda9866da446a72e206d6484cd97381cbc7859a7068541c36;C:\Projects;C:\Users\kelly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\;C:\Users\kelly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\;C:\Users\kelly\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the whole error traceback message.

Comment: Also show us the exact command you used to run this code.

Comment: I launch it from Sublime using CTRL B. (specifically from the file making_pizzas.py

Comment: In the question you say you have a file named `make_pizza.py`, but the error message says you're actually running `making_pizzas.py`.  Which is it?

Comment: Also, the question says the error message is `No module named error`, but the error message says `No module named 'pizza'`.  Again, which is it?

Comment: I have corrected my earlier entry to 'making_pizza' .  This is my first post to stack overflow.  I am a bit of nube.  The module I am trying to import is pizza.   This seems like a really minor task and I don't understand why it is not working.

Comment: Show us the output of this code `import os; print(os.getcwd()); print(os.listdir())`

Comment: I usually encounter this error when trying to run my code on a remote machine, since they don't know what the project looks like like the local IDE. My fast way to fix is to add something like `sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/your/project')` at the start of the code.

Comment: C:\Projects\Pizza
['making_pizzas.py', 'pizza.py', 'testing.py', '__init__.py']
[Finished in 0.2s]

Comment: testing.py contains the code you requested @John Gordon

Comment: Well, this is odd.  I don't see the problem either.  Is the filename `pizza.py` exactly as you have shown?  It's just plain ascii letters, no unicode?  And the same with the code line `import pizza` -- no special characters?

Comment: What are the permissions on the file `pizza.py`?  Is it globally readable?

Comment: Permissions look good at this time for both files. Other than the permissions I am not sure what you mean by globally readable.